# How to set multiple CSS display property values with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, this is driving me a bit batty. I am using the jQuery .css() method to *try* to set the multiple flexbox display properties needed for a class. Problem is, it only keeps the last one. Any idea on how to do this with jQuery, or is it not possible?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
$(".department-name").css({
    'display' : '-webkit-box',
    'display' : '-webkit-flex',
    'display' : '-moz-box',
    'display' : '-ms-flexbox',
    'display' : 'flex'
});
```

That doesn't work, it just gets the last one and not the others. I am manipulating a text element on a page based on how many line wraps it has (its height) and want to hide it with display:none (initial CSS value), manipulate it, then display it with the flex properties it had before I started changing the JS code to deal with the multiple line problem. Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.department-name').addClass('test1');
```

css:

```
.test1{
   display : -webkit-box;
   display : -webkit-flex;
   display : -moz-box;
   display : -ms-flexbox;
   display : flex;
}
```

You can use `addClass()` method to add test class into your element. in `css()` method display property must be getting overrides hence the last one is only applying.

Comment: Definitely better than my answer. This is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Store it in a variable:

```js
var displayStyle = [
  'display: -webkit-box',
  'display: -webkit-flex',
  'display: -moz-box',
  'display: -ms-flexbox',
  'display: flex'
].join(';');


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".department-name").attr('style', displayStyle);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='department-name'>TEST</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. There is an `h4` inside that `.departmentname` `div` that I changed the `display` property for, so problem solved.  Thanks for the feedback though.